# Hibernate cant delete one to one mapped entity in cascade

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities mapped one to one:

Entity1:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "entity2", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
Entity2 entity2;
```

Entity2:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "entity1_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
private Entity1 entity1;
```

Entity1 by itself is mapped many to one to another entity SuperEntity defined in Entity1 as following:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "superentity_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private SuperEntity superEntity;
```

I deleting a SuperEntity using `deleteById` method. All mapped Entity1 deleting as expected, but for every Entity2 I receive a following errors:

```
HHH000114: Handling transient entity in delete processing

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Removing a detached instance
```

My expectation was that Entity2 should be deleted along with associated Entity1.

What is the reason for this behavior and how I can fix it?
I am using a Spring Boot 3.1.2 with Hibernate 6.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're encountering this behavior is due to the orphan removal cascade option set on the @OneToOne mapping between Entity1 and Entity2. When you delete the SuperEntity, Hibernate tries to cascade the deletion to the associated Entity1 instances. However, because of the orphan removal cascade option, Hibernate tries to delete the associated Entity2 instances as well.

The error message "HHH000114: Handling transient entity in delete processing" indicates that Hibernate is trying to delete a transient (i.e., detached) entity, which is Entity2 in this case.

You can remove the orphanRemoval = true option from the @OneToOne mapping in Entity1.

Comment: I tried that, but it is still the same errors over and over. Besides, I made it clearer in edit, the behavior I expect that Entity2 instance should be deleted along with the Entity1.